# HTML foreign language characters

Tags: php, html, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression To Anglicize String Characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174089/regular-expression-to-anglicize-string-characters)

What would be the best way to convert foreign language characters to english ones? For example ü to u.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769457/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string

Comment: if its the right character in the context it should be kept, not 'converted'

Comment: @Chris Fulstow - Considering the solution is PHP, not .Net, the 2nd two questions aren't relevant.  And considering that a regex is *not* the right way to do this...  ;)

Comment: @John: But the method described within particularly the second link _is_ the right one in general – decompose into base Latin characters and diacriticals, then strip the diacriticals. Anything else has tough edge cases and requires a very large list of things to change.

Comment: @Donal - Possibly... except that PHP doesn't have a string.Normalize.  You'd need to utilize the full mapping table.  While this may be the 'right' answer, such a table is large and unwieldy.  I think it depends on the author's intent... to which I have no insight.  Generally, I am not fan of doing this at all, but know that there are certain circumstances where it is needed and appropriate.  The solution I propose below is a 'quick' solution, which I would recommend for things like URL replacement or filename setting... and I would not suggest anybody do this for most any other reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a couple of reasons to do this (url friendliness, mostly).  You want [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

It basically works like this:

```
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
```

The 2nd comment in the manual has a nice translation table for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $text = mb_str_replace('ü','u', $text);
```

To find all non English character using:

```
 preg_match('#[^a-z0-9\-\.\,\:\;]#', $text, $characters);
```